# Why use Case in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause

I know there are variations of this question out there but cannot find one that answers what I am looking for.

I have inherited a database and reports from another programmer who is no longer in the picture.

One of the Queries uses this code:

```
Select
     b.HospitalMasterID
    ,b.TxnSite
    ,b.PatientID
    ,b.TxnDate as KeptDate
From
    Billing as b
    Inner Join Patient as p
        on b.HospitalMasterID = p.HospitalMasterID
        and b.PatientID = p.PatientID
Where
    b._IsServOrItem=1
    and b.TxnDate >= '20131001'
    and (Case
            When b.ExtendedAmount > 0 Then 1
            When (Not(p.PlanCode is null)) and (b.listAmount >0) then 1
        End = 1)
```

When I run the Query I get apx 900,000 rows returned.  If I remove the Case statement, I get over a million rows returned.

Can someone explain why this is so?  What exactly is the case statement doing?  Is there a better way to accomplish the same thing.  I really don't like this statement as it stands and the entire report query is very difficult to read due to lack of structure.

Version of Sql is T-Sql 2012.

Thanks,

Comment: It could be an artifact left from earlier code that had more `WHEN` clauses, or someone may have expected to be adding more later and it seemed like a good idea. It even avoids using `p.PlanCode is not NULL`. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's someone trying to avoid using the `OR` operator in order to promote index seeks over scans. It would be worth looking at the plan, but I would be surprised if it differed significantly over the logic in Greg's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to me like it's doing this:

```
(b.ExtendedAmount > 0 OR (Not(p.PlanCode is null) and (b.listAmount >0)))
```

Maybe it was copy / pasted from somewhere else and modified?  Regardless, it's bizarre.

Comment: Thanks- that is what I figured, what I can't figure is why is it changing the results of the query?  I can only think that it was built with the Query Builder which throws weird coding in and it was also built using SSRS, not directly in SSMS.  Just wish I knew why the 100K row difference on results.